# Content Porter: Why are my security settings not copied to target system?

Tags: content-porter-2013

We created a publication and implemented group security settings in SDL Tridion 2013.

When exporting the publication and importing it to another system, we expected that the security settings would also be copied to the target system, but they were not. How can I achieve this result?

Comment: I doubt you will get much help in case the question is not descriptive. To be frank I am unable to understand your question. I recommend you go to the FAQ section of the site, learn how you should ask the question. It would be good if you can tell what all steps you are following with details, what you have tried so far to resolve, is there any errors in the event log etc.

Comment: And on top of what @PankajGaur explains, forget about asking for a solution ASAP, this is a community initiative, all members here will do their utmost best to answer your question, provided it is clear and answerable (which yours is not at the moment). Nobody here will consider a certain question above another based on any type of urgency, that is not the way this works.

Answer (score 5):

The [online documentation](http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Content%20Porter%20full%20documentation-v1/GUID-B562B17F-6112-43CD-AE4B-84F370B4C4F8) (login required) highlights a number of items that are 'non-exportable' when using Content Porter:

> An export cannot export the following items:
>
> - Font definitions
> - Protocol Schemas in publishing
> - Schemas in publishing
> - Target types in publishing
> - Publication Targets in publishing
> - Page and Component publishing status
> - Users
> - **Security settings for Users and Groups**
> - **Permissions for Publications, Folders, and Structure Groups**
> - Checked-in and checked-out status for Components, Template Building Blocks, Component Templates, Page Templates, Pages, and Schemas
> - History list for Components, Template Building Blocks, Component Templates, Page Templates, and Pages
> - Approval Status of individual items

As is highlighted in bold, there are a number of security items that are not exported using Content Porter.

If it is just a small number of Groups and Publications, then I suggest that you set these manually in each environment.

For a larger scale, you may want to consider scripting this with Powershell (or similar). [Dominic](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/129/dominic-cronin) has an excellent blog post on [How to set Rights and Permissions using the SDL Tridion core service API](http://www.indivirtual.nl/blog/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/) which may give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Although the content porter does not support managing your security settings across your environments, you can take care of this in other ways. For example, when you release a content porter package to your downstream environments, you could also provide a security settings script which the administrator can execute. This should be less error-prone than issuing manual instructions.

To create such a script, you can use the Powershell and the Core service. I have written [a blog article which explains how to do this](http://www.indivirtual.nl/blog/set-rights-permissions-using-sdl-tridion-core-service-api/).